# How to get instance ID from reservation ID in boto

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm trying to create a simple script upon which I can build using the boto module in python. I want to define a few functions that would allow me to create and terminate instances. I'm having trouble getting an instance ID, which is needed for the terminate portion. I can get reservation IDs from the get_all_instances() attribute, but I can't figure out an easy way to take a given reservation ID and from it get the instance ID.

If it's not painfully obvious, I'm new to python and haven't got the hang of equating the different types.

If I had a Reservation ID, res = Reservation:r-xxxxxxx, I haven't found anywhere in the API doc how to call the instance ID related. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first point I would make is that a reservation can have more than one instance associated with it.  It's not always a one-to-one mapping.  If you call `run_instances` and request more than one instance to be created, all of them will be associated to the same reservation.

You say you are using the `get_all_instances` method.  This method returns a list of Reservation objects.  Each of those Reservation objects could potentially have multiple Instance objects associated with it.  The Reservation objects aren't all that useful so usually what you want to do is just turn the list of Reservation objects into a list of Instance objects right away.  One way to do this is:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')  # or whatever region you want
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()  # could limit results with filters
instances = []
for r in reservations:
    instances.extend(r.instances)
```

The variable `instances` should now be a list of Instance objects.  Each Instance object has an attribute called `id` that contains it's unique instance id.

A more compact way of doing the same thing would be to use nested list comprehensions, like this:

```
# same first three lines as above
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That works. So is there not a way to directly call just the instance IDs?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "directly call just the instance IDs".  The only way to find out about instances is the DescribeInstances request (which get_all_instances calls) and it always returns a list of Reservation objects with one or more instances inside each.

Comment: I want to create two functions, one that would launch an instance based on a given set of parameters, and then a function that could take the return of the launch function to terminate what gets returned from the launch function. So far, all I see that gets returned from launching an instance using boto.ec2 is the Reservation object. I'm trying to figure out how to use that as a parameter that would inform the terminate function what to terminate. Since the call to terminate needs the instance ID or IDs, that's why I'm trying to get one from the other.

Comment: Right.  So, you have to look inside that Reservation object that is returned by the boto run_instances method and grab the instance ID's as shown above.  You could then have your launch function just return the instance ID's since you really have no use for the Reservation object.

Comment: Great. Yes. That was a lot simpler than I was making it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not what the op wants - but, an easier way might be to create an instance object when you start the instance. e.g.

```
import boto.ec2

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1")

ins1 = conn.run_instances('ami-0axxxxxx', key_name='default', instance_type='t2.micro', security_group_ids=['sg-0c000000'], subnet_id='subnet-777777')

instance = ins1.instances[0]

print instance.id
```

Comment: Forgot about the key=value pairs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This code will print all instance id from all reservations. Hope it helps.

```
import boto3

ec2=boto3.client('ec2')
instance_information = ec2.describe_instances()

c = boto3.ec2.connect_to_region('ap-south-1')
for reservation in instance_information['Reservations']:
    for instance in reservation['Instances']:
        print instance["InstanceId"]
```